# SUSE 15 SP2 AD Authentication: Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: suse, active-directory, kerberos

I am trying to configure configure Active Directory authentication on a SLE 15 SP2 host.
The AD-domain exists of multiple DCs/AD-servers.

I followed these guides:
https://www.suse.com/c/the-sssd-active-directory-and-sles-12-and-15/
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019549

When i configured the host to use ONE specific AD-server everything worked fine. But when I configure the host to fetch the different servers it also works fine for a while then it stops working.I can SSH without any problems authenticating against the AD-account in the group but the SSSD-service gives multiple lines of the following error:

"Oct 12 08:46:45 host sssd[15569]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information, Minor = Server not found in Kerberos database."

I have tried multiple configs from different sites but none has helped me.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Config files:

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss,pam
domains = dom-ain.domain.com

[nss]
filter_users = root
filter_groups = root

[pam]

[domain/dom-ain.domain.com]
debug_level=6
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
cache_credentials = false
enumerate = false
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
case_sensitive = true
ad_hostname = host.dom-ain.domain.com
simple_allow_groups = GR_host@dom-ain.domain.com
access_provider = simple
```

**krb5.conf**

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d

[libdefaults]
    dns_canonicalize_hostname = false
    rdns = false
    default_realm = DOM-AIN.DOMAIN.COM
    default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    allow_weak_crypto = false

[domain_realm]
    .dom-ain.domain.com = DOM-AIN.DOMAIN.COM
    dom-ain.domain.com = DOM-AIN.DOMAIN.COM

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmind.log
    default = SYSLOG:NOTICE:DAEMO

[realms]
    DOM-AIN.DOMAIN.COM = {
        default_domain = dom-ain.domain.com
    }
```

**ldap.conf**

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

URI ldap:// dom-ain.domain.com
BASE dc=doma-ain,dc=domain,dc=com

REFERRALS FF

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never
```

**nsswitch.conf**

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Legal entries are:
#
#       compat                  Use compatibility setup
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files
#       [NOTFOUND=return]       Stop searching if not found so far
#
# For more information, please read the nsswitch.conf.5 manual page.
#

passwd: compat sss
group:  compat sss
shadow: compat

hosts:  files dns
networks:   files dns

services:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:    files
ethers: files
netmasks:   files
netgroup:   files nis
publickey:  files

bootparams: files
automount:  files nis
aliases:    files
```

**smb.conf**

```
# smb.conf is the main Samba configuration file. You find a full commented
# version at /usr/share/doc/packages/samba/examples/smb.conf.SUSE if the
# samba-doc package is installed.
#[global]
#   workgroup = DOM-AIN
#   passdb backend = tdbsam
#   printing = cups
#   printcap name = cups
#   printcap cache time = 750
#   cups options = raw
#   map to guest = Bad User
#   logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
#   logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
#   logon drive = P:
#   usershare allow guests = Yes
[global]
    workgroup = DOM-AIN
    client signing = yes
    client use spnego = yes
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    realm = DOM-AIN.DOMAIN.COM
    security = ADS
    create krb5 conf = no

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
[profiles]
    comment = Network Profiles Service
    path = %H
    read only = No
    store dos attributes = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
[users]
    comment = All users
    path = /home
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    veto files = /aquota.user/groups/shares/
[groups]
    comment = All groups
    path = /home/groups
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = No
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @ntadmin root
    force group = ntadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you are using sssd with a version of Samba >= 4.8.0 This is not supported unless you just require authentication and even then it isn't supported by red-hat (the producers of sssd), you must use winbind. If Suse is still suggesting using sssd, then they need to update their documentation.

Comment: @RowlandPenny Thanks for the info!